# javascript and css loads but not working on navigation in React js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router

I am working in react js. I put all the assets links in public/index.html. When i start project, only first page works fine. When i navigate to other pages, all pages does not show the correct resul, and when i  get back to first page it does not work. I checked the css and javascript files by ctrl+u. All files are loaded. The Both source files, before navigate and after navigate are same all files are loaded but on navigation it does not work. Please have a look on my index.html, how i use link tag to import css and javascript file. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank [image]

I put all links to app.js and assets moved to src directory. Css files are working but jquery shows following error
[image]

Comment: I am using jsx for html rendering

Comment: Should i use Js and css files  separately for each component ? I pull all links in index.html is this a correct way ?

Comment: best way to import css in App.js file. instead of adding in index.html

Comment: https://app.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-import-components-from-react-bootstrap - here is tutorial to import css

Comment: i don't wanna use react-boostrap. I want to import my custom css and and bootstrap 4 i downloaded. Because theme is ready made

Comment: i think you should share your JS files not that public_html

Answer (score -1):

import your CSS file in the "App.js" file. It'll work

Comment: you are right. I added files to app.js. Css files works but jquery files showing error. Image attached above. I just edited question

Comment: You have misunderstood my answer. You don't have to import jquery and other stuff in app.js. Only import CSS file.

Comment: than js files do not work

Comment: can you explain it, please?